# snapcraft: "AttributeError: module 'click' has no attribute 'group'"

Tags: snap

I updated my clone of snapcraft master to the latest revision. Now I'm seeing this error trying to do anything:

```
AttributeError: module 'click' has no attribute 'group'
```

I'm running snapcraft in a venv and had all the development packages installed before as per HACKING.md.

Answer (score 0):

There are two python modules called `click`. One is the precursor of the snap packaging format, which was used in Ubuntu Touch: https://launchpad.net/click

The other one is a tool for command line user interfaces: http://click.pocoo.org/

This last one is the one that snapcraft requires.

The error you are getting means that you have installed the deb package for the wrong click module. Remove it with:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge python3-click-package
```